# Is there a Registry key that indicates if a user is an admin or not?

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry

As the title says I'd like to give or take away admin rights by changing a Registry key. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Not possible from the registry.

This is typically done by using the Local User Manager ("C:\windows\system32\lusrmgr.msc")  If you navigate to groups > Administrators, you can add and remove users from the admin groups.

You can also Add and remove users from Administrators in a number of ways including the [Net LocalGroup](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490706.aspx) command:

```
net localgroup "Administrators""RandomUsername"/add
net localgroup "Administrators""RandomUsername"/delete
```

Answer (score 0):

No. But if it were possible, you'd have to have Admin rights to make the change, and since you have these rights, you can look at membership in the `Administrators` group to determine if a user has Admin rights.

For more information look at the `net user` command.